# Django is throwing a "[123L, 123L] is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, django, json, django-views, jsonserializer

in my code i have:

```
json.dumps({'foo': {'bar': [123L, 123L]}})
```

the long ints are primary keys. this line for some reason generates the error:

"[123L, 123L] is not JSON serializable"

When i try to execute it in python manage.py shell:

```
json.dumps({'foo': {'bar': [123L, 123L]}})
```

works fine.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

exact Django error:

Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    [123L] is not JSON serializable
Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py in default, line 192

Comment: Well for starters the code which you posted is missing a closing brace (`}`)...

Comment: Can you show us the (smallest) complete code that throws the exception?

Comment: try casting to 123L to an int

Comment: Can you give us more information about your environment? Django version, OS, etc.

Comment: I just realized what the actual problem is: [123L, 123L] is of type ValuesListQuerySet - I need to somehow convert it to a list.

Comment: Seems like you are using a version of simplejson thats not in the django distribution? Is it old?

Comment: @9-bits ah there you go, that's easily done: `list_of_numbers = list(my_values_list_queryset)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from django.db.models.query import ValuesListQuerySet

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, ValuesListQuerySet):
        return list(o)
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

json.dumps(valueListObject, default=default)
```